# How can I go about automating the testing of the migration of local web apps from IE6 to IE8?

Tags: testing, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-8, migration

I have been researching this a wee bit and it seems to boil down to:

'Eyeball Mark 1'

The best tip seems to be the use of SuperPreview from Microsoft's Expression team.

If anyone has automated a way to go about this I would love to hear about it.

Also, I believe that SuperPreview requires a work around for a password protected app to work properly. There is a work around at [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/xweb/archive/2009/07/27/site-authentication-and-superpreview.aspx), but if anyone has come up with another way, could you share it with me please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some products, like Telerik WebUI Test Studio, lets you build your test and play a movie with the results in different browsers (not sure about IE6 and IE8 support)

Others lets you compare bitmaps of screenshots of tests in one browser and the other. The problem is that the minimum 1-bit shift will result in an test error.